# JWT Authentication .NET Core 2.2 doesn't update HttpContext

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, jwt

I've searched through some similar questions, but none helped me. I have the following situation:

Basic JWT authentication in .NET Core 2.2, Startup.cs has its settings as:

**Startup.cs**

```cs
            public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
            {
                ...

                var signingConfigurations = new SigningConfigurations();
                services.AddSingleton(signingConfigurations);
                var tokenConfigurations = new TokenConfigurations();
                new ConfigureFromConfigurationOptions<TokenConfigurations>(
                    Configuration.GetSection("TokenConfigurations"))
                        .Configure(tokenConfigurations);
                services.AddSingleton(tokenConfigurations);

                services.AddAuthentication(authOptions =>
                {
                    authOptions.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                    authOptions.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                }).AddJwtBearer(bearerOptions =>
                {
                    var paramsValidation = bearerOptions.TokenValidationParameters;
                    paramsValidation.IssuerSigningKey = signingConfigurations.Key;
                    paramsValidation.ValidAudience = tokenConfigurations.Audience;
                    paramsValidation.ValidIssuer = tokenConfigurations.Issuer;

                    // Validates a received token signature
                    paramsValidation.ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true;

                    // Verifies if a received token is still valid
                    paramsValidation.ValidateLifetime = true;

                    // Tolerance time for token expiration (used if there are timezone differences)
                    paramsValidation.ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero;
                });

                // Activates token usage on this project
                services.AddAuthorization(auth =>
                {
                    auth.AddPolicy("Bearer", new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
                        .AddAuthenticationSchemes(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                        .RequireAuthenticatedUser().Build());
                });
```

Then, to generate the token:

**LoginController.cs**

```cs
        if (validCredentials)
        {
            ClaimsIdentity declarations = new ClaimsIdentity(
                new GenericIdentity(userInDB.UserName, "Login"),
                new[] {
                    new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Jti, Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N")),
                    new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.UniqueName, userInDB.UserName),
                    new Claim("userid", userInDB.Id, ClaimValueTypes.String),
                    new Claim("username", userInDB.UserName, ClaimValueTypes.String),
                }
            );

            DateTime creationDate = DateTime.Now;
            DateTime expirationDate = creationDate +
                TimeSpan.FromSeconds(tokenConfigurations.Seconds);

            var handler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
            var securityToken = handler.CreateToken(new SecurityTokenDescriptor
            {
                Issuer = tokenConfigurations.Issuer,
                Audience = tokenConfigurations.Audience,
                SigningCredentials = signingConfigurations.SigningCredentials,
                Subject = declarations,
                NotBefore = creationDate,
                Expires = expirationDate
            });
            var token = handler.WriteToken(securityToken);

            return new
            {
                authenticated = true,
                created = creationDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"),
                expiration = expirationDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"),
                accessToken = token,
                message = "OK"
            };
        }
```

All I did so far is based on [this](https://medium.com/@renato.groffe/asp-net-core-2-0-autentica%C3%A7%C3%A3o-em-apis-utilizando-jwt-json-web-tokens-4b1871efd) walkthrough

So far, so good. If I add `[Authorize("Bearer")]` on a controller, it can be accessed only if I have the bearer on the header of the request.

But as I was implementing an UserSession structure, to intercept any request, go through the HttpContext and fill the UserSession object, it just doesn't work. The responsible method is this:

**ApplicationBuilderExtensions.cs**

```cs
        public static IApplicationBuilder UseSessionConfiguration(
            this IApplicationBuilder builder)
        {
            return builder.UseMiddleware<SessionConfigurationMiddleware>();
        }

        public class SessionConfigurationMiddleware
        {
            private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

            public SessionConfigurationMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
            {
                _next = next;
            }

            public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context, IUserSession sessao)
            {
                if (context.User.Identities.Any(id => id.IsAuthenticated))
                {
                    sessao.UserId = context.User.Claims.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Type == "userid").Value;
                    sessao.Roles = context.User.Claims.Where(x => x.Type == "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/role").Select(x => x.Value).ToList();
                    sessao.UserName = context.User.Claims.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Type == "username").Value;
                }

                // Call the next delegate/middleware in the pipeline
                await _next.Invoke(context);
            }
        }
```

But, as I debbug this portion of the code (which is correctly being called after any request) the `IsAuthenticated` property on the HttpContext is always false, in fact, everything is null, or empty on the `context.User` and I have no idea why.

Am I configuring the jwt wrong?
Is the middleware not correct?
Am I filling the Claims on the jwt correctly?
Why is `[Authorize("Bearer")]` working correctly if `HttpContext` is not properly filled?
Are we alone in the universe?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your middleware is called before or after app.UseAuthentication() in startup.cs?

Comment: it is called after app.UseAuthentication();

Comment: @DiegoPenha did you find a solution for this problem?